# Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I am using Sonarqube for code analysis and have integrated Jenkins with it. But when I run the Jenkin Project to scan the java code residing in bitbucket, it fails with an error "**Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main**

**java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0**"

[image: Jenkins task failing issue]

What might be the issue?